# How to create checkout session for payment intent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, stripe-payments

I'm using `stripe` to create an payment integration in my system, after creating an `payment intent` i want to create `checkout session` for this payment, after this i want to retrieve an `url` property from this checkout and send to the user.

But i don't have an idea how to "connect" created payment intent to checkout session.

Right now i create payment intent in this way:

```
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
      {
        amount: 500,
        currency: "usd",
        customer: customerId
      },
      {
        stripeAccount: ""
      }
    );
```

and checkout session:

```
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      success_url: "",
      cancel_url: "",
      mode: "payment",
      customer: customerId,
      payment_method_types: ["card"]
    });
```

The problem is in this, that i don't know how to create checkout session based on created before an payment intent.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The Checkout Session itself will create a PaymentIntent. You can create an equivalent PaymentIntent with the `line_items.price_data.unit_amount`[1], `line_items.price_data.currency`[2], and `customer`[3] parameters of the `checkout.sessions.create` call. Make sure to pass in the `stripeAccount` parameter to your Session creation call as well if you want to create the Session/PaymentIntent on their account.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data-unit_amount

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data-currency

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer

Comment: Ok, thanks, but one more question about this, How to create checkout with `mode=setup` and charge money from the customer at the same moment? Right now i cannot set `mode=setup` on create checkout because i must to add price_data

Comment: Or is the way to save payment method on the future payment?

Comment: Checkout cannot charge a customer in setup mode. In payment mode you can set `payment_intent_data.setup_future_usage` to save the payment method and attach it to your customer. Setting `setup_future_usage` to `on_session` will simply save the payment method, `off_session` will save the payment method and optimize it for off session payments like subscription auto renewals if you need that functionality.
 https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-setup_future_usage